# Webview Status Code in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-webview

I checked this following java [resource](https://github.com/letusfly85/step-up-android/wiki/get-status-code-of-webview) to get the status code of Webview for Xamarin Android from c#. As from Xamarin documentation [WebResourceResponse(String, String, Stream)](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Webkit.WebResourceResponse/) Stream api is of type ***System.IO.Stream***. I need to convert ***Java.IO.InputStream*** to ***System.IO.Stream***.

Is it possible convert these type?. if not what could be the possible fix. I am new to Xamarin. Please help.

```
private static string http = "https?://[\\w\\.\\-]+(/.*)?";
Regex regex = new Regex(http);

public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(WebView webView, string url)
{
    if (!regex.IsMatch(http))
    {
        return ShouldInterceptRequest(webView, url);
    }

    HttpGet req= new HttpGet(url);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String mimetype = null, encoding = null;

    byte[] data = null;

    try
    {
        var response = client.Execute(req); 

        if (HttpStatus.ScOk == response.StatusLine.StatusCode)
        {
            var httpentity = response.Entity;
            var header = httpentity.ContentType;

            if (null != mimetype) mimetype = header.Value;

            var encodingheader = httpentity.ContentEncoding;
            if (null != encodingheader) encoding = encodingheader.Value;

            data = EntityUtils.ToByteArray(httpentity);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String msg = e.Message;
        Log.Error(this.Class.SimpleName, (null != msg) ? msg : "");
    }
    finally
    {
        req.Abort();
        client.ConnectionManager.Shutdown();
    }

    Java.IO.InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    // this is the error i get
    // cannot convert from 'Java.IO.InputStream' to 'System.IO.Stream'
    // Argument type 'Java.IO.InputStream' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.IO.Stream'
    return new WebResourceResponse(mimetype, encoding, stream);

}
```

Comment: You can use `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);` to handle the `data`. You can't convert Java.IO.InputStream to System.IO.Stream. You can write on the file by java and read the file by c#, but it is not a good solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did use the `MemoryStream` api. It fixed the error. should I  post the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible convert these type?

The answer is No. You can't convert directly, you can use file to achieve it, but it will make the problem complex.

In your problem, you can use [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) class, it can accept `Byte[]` as parameter in its construct.

Replace

```
Java.IO.InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

with:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
```